# Allowing write permissions for WordPress in WebMatrix

Tags: windows-7, permissions, file-management, wordpress

I'm giving Microsoft WebMatrix a shot and have installed WordPress. However I can't get it to save files. I'm getting the following error:

> The uploaded file could not be moved to D:\WebMatrix\Test_Site/wp-content/uploads/2011/04.

I've tried setting the write permissions for the NETWORK SERVICE account on WebMatrix to no avail. Any ideas what the problem is?